# Yii PHP framework tutorials

Tags: php, yii

Since, I am new to Yii framwork,

I am not able to find some good documented tutorials apart from their official documentation and no video tutorials at all.

Could you guyz please share some links having proper module wise tutorials.

Thanks

Comment: just use the official website and also, create a new project and take a look inside the source code; there are many extensions and components;

Comment: could anyone tell me why downvote for this question?

Comment: Even though I am not disputing the earnestness in your question, Stack Overflow doesn't encourage subjective questions which is the reason why you are getting downvoted. Upvoted you if it makes it better but ask questions like these on the official yii site, some real awesome people there to help you.

Comment: this is not a question

Comment: wtf..!! I have seen 100s of questions on stackoverflow asking about the good resources. And when I have asked this type of question you are saying its not a question. I have just got 4 downvots Its insane.

Comment: There are more vigilantes than people with helping mentality

Answer (score 4):

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/268/how-to-learn-yii/
This link would be a great place to start.

This is where I started an a couple months ago, and I am pretty much through over everything it has to offer. Remember to follow the pattern for the CRUD operations for the auto-generated code using gii. Once you wrap your head around it, you would be good to start coding . Cheers :)

Answer (score 3):

`Yii` have provide a **"Building blog tutorial"**. You can refer this link: 
`[http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/][1]`.

It quite completed. I also learn from [the link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/).